# Accessing /page/2 on WordPress directly breaks infinite-scroll

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I added infinite-scroll.js library to Wordpress (manually, not via plugin). On index i have wrote a loop to make the pagination and everything works fine, however then i'm accessing URL/page/2 directly not from index i see that it is broken. Any ideas how to avoid this? Maybe doing some redirect to index when accessing page/x/ or any other way? Or maybe it is possible to preload everything from index (page1) and continue loading on page/2?

Also tried if is_paged -> when redirect to index on index.php template file. This method works, but of course infinite-scroll doesn't load any new items.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code for your loop?

Comment: Yes, sure: `<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( '&showposts=10' . '&cat=1' . '&paged='.$paged);
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {  ?>
<div id="container">
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) { $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="item">

// content

<?php } ?></div><?php } else { ?>
<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`